# Purpose of secondary dependent styles?

Tags: gwt

I'm just going through the [GWT Tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial) and one point which just don't understand is when and why to use dependent secondary styles. If I define a style in the .css stylesheet, and use the `addStyleName` method it seems to have the same effect.

E.g. applying a secondary dependent style to a button or applying the it as a non-dependant style seems to yield the exact same results.

Comment: Here's a very good article about this topic and styles: http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/12/gwt-no-need-to-shortchange-your-style.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the dependent name is more general, since it's calculated at runtime.  You can add a dependent name of "highlighted" to any `Widget` without knowing what it is, and GWT will come up with the appropriate css class name for you.  You don't have to hard code button-highlighted, select-highlighted, mycustomthing-highlighted in GWT this way (you do still need to create them all in your css code).

Comment: but what's the reason behind this? i could easily add "primary" style "highlighted" and in css declare .myWidgetStyle.highlighted {color:red} to achieve same result